# Can't give input to programs ran in neovim

Tags: c++, python-3.x, vim, neovim

When I run code written in C++ or python I can't give Input to the program.
For c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int test;
    scanf("%d", &test);
    printf("%d\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs

```
:!g++ -o run test.cpp && ./run  2>&1| tee /tmp/nvimPNNwAf/3                                                                                            
32767

(1 of 1): 32767
```

For python3

```
test = input()
```

Outputs

```
:!python3 test.py                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  test = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

shell returned 1
```

I know I can use `:term` and it would fix it. But I'm having problems with `:term`.

When I input:

```
3
10 12 3 9
10 12 7 2
13 11 5 6
```

It should look like:

```
3
10 12 3 9
10 12 7 2
13 11 5 6
33
-1
83
```

However, it outputs:

```
3                       
10 12 3 9    
10 13                   
2 7 2    
13 11 5 6      
1             
1
```

How can I fix this issue?
(This didn't happen in Vim)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, this is not a big but rather a feature as interactive shell was disabled in neovim, you can see justimk answer on this GitHub issue   https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496
The solution is to invoke your program outside neovim or use a plug-in to do so.